Different NDVI values using Landsat-9 and Sentinel-2 satellite imagery using QGIS3
In QGIS3, I have calculated NDVI values using Sentinel-2 and Landsat-9 images for the same region and approximately the same date and then checked the "STATISTICS_MEAN" values in the NDVI Layers Information box for the two sources.  The results are vastly different (~0.7 for Landsat, which appears to be reasonable given the region of study, and ~0.4 for Sentinel, which seems too low).  I have processed the raw Landsat images per the guidelines provided by USGS-EROS (scale factor and offset), but I just used the raw data for Sentinel-2.  Any guidance as to why there should be such a difference?  Is there some pre-processing that needs to be done to the raw Sentinel-2 images?  I am aware that the raw Sentinel-2 image data needs to be converted to the range 0-1 by dividing values by 10,000, but I can't see how that would change the results of the NDVI calculation.

Are you using L1C or L2A data ?

L1C is in TOA (top of atmosphere) reflectance
L2A is in BOA (bottom of atmosphere) reflectance
Note that you have Sentinel-2 with surface reflectance computed from the THEIA pole.

But if you want to do harmonized comparison between S2 and Landsat, you should maybe checkout the Harmonized Landsat-Sentinel products, that have been carefully harmonized in such goal.
PS: note that for recent S2 product (after processing baseline 04.00), dividing by 10,000 is not enough, you should also remove the bias as said in this post.

My workflow Part 1:Download Sentinel-2 L2A image files for band 4 and 8.
Files are named:  T16TDQ_20240802T163901_B04_10m.jp2;  T16TDQ_20240802T163901_B08_10m.jp2
Load band 4 and 8 rasters into QGIS-3.
Ranges are:  B04_10m.jp2 – 542 to 10,192;  B08_10m.jp2 – 7 to 10,994
Clip band 4 and 8 to small, heavily wooded area.
Options are: Match the extent of the clipped raster to the extent of the mask layer; Keep resolution of input raster.
Resolution: 30 columns by 24 rows
Ranges are: B04_10m_Clipped – 0 to 1,406; B08_10m_Clipped – 0 to 3,534

My workflow Part 2:  Scale clipped band 4 and 8 rasters by dividing by 10,000.
Ranges are: B04_10m_Scaled – 0 to 0.1406; B08_10m_Scaled – 0 to 0.3534
Set band 4 and 8 raster values of 0 to no data.
Ranges are: B04_10m_No_Data – 0.128 to 0.1406; B08_10m_Scaled – 0.2866 to 0.3534
Calculate NDVI.
Ranges are: Min = 0.359; Mean = 0.407; Max = 0.463
